# Laravel 5.2 AJAX validation alert message won't show to laravel view

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use ajax to display errors. for example if the form input is empty. It worked but it doesn't go to it's view. Every time i execute the program with empty form it is showing this.

[image]

I am expecting it will showing alert like this

[image]

here is my controller

```
public function storeamp(Request $request){

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'guru_id' => 'required',
        'mapel_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->passes()) {

        $ada = Mengampu::where('guru_id', $request['guru_id'])->where('mapel_id', $request['mapel_id'])->get()->count();

        if($ada > 0){
            Session::flash('tolong', 'Data Exist!');
            return redirect()->to('guru/ampu');
        } else{ 
            return response()->json(['success'=>'Added new records.']);
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
```

and here is my ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
            var guru_id = $("input[name='guru_id']").val();
            var mapel_id = $("input[name='mapel_id']").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type:'POST',
                data: {_token:_token, guru_id:guru_id, mapel_id:mapel_id},
                success: function(data){
                    if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                         $('div.flash-message').html(data);

                    } else {
                        printMessageErrors(data.error)
                    }          
                },
            });
                function printMessageErrors(msg){
                $(".print-error-msg").find('ul').html('');
                $(".print-error-msg").css('display','block');

                $.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
                    $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
                });
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

here is div where i put `print-error-msg`. i put it above `<form>`

```
<div class="alert alert-danger print-error-msg" style="display:none">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: you want to show the error in your view, do you?

Comment: console.log the value in each() function . be sure you get the error value there

Comment: i mean if validation form is empty @JamesRiady i expect to show it on my view with alert div. let me update the question

Comment: you can't use return response.. because return response will return json.. you have to return view with your error variable and then in your view.. you can check the error like `if the error is not empty then foreach the error and show the alert`, do you get it?

Comment: how should i change the code? @JamesRiady

Comment: I have posted my answer, you can try it.. I think you are using AdminLTE template, are you? AdminLTE has provided an example how to show error in view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller

```
public function storeamp(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'guru_id' => 'required',
    'mapel_id' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->passes()) {

    $ada = Mengampu::where('guru_id', $request['guru_id'])->where('mapel_id', $request['mapel_id'])->get()->count();

    if($ada > 0){
        Session::flash('tolong', 'Data Exist!');
        return redirect()->to('guru/ampu');
    } else{ 
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Added new records.']);
    }
}

$errors = $validator->errors()->all();
return view(hello.world)->with('errors', $errors);
}
```

View

```
<div class="alert alert-danger print-error-msg" style="display: {{ count($errors) > 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }}">
        <ul>
        @foreach($errors as $error)
          <li>{{$error['error']}}</li> 
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I think if your project is only focus on using laravel, you don't need to use ajax to store your data.. laravel provide route to connect your controller and your view..
Hope this can help you to solve your problem

Comment: ohhh thanks! That solved my problem! :D Hope you have a great day!

Comment: Please do tick in my answer if it solves your problem.. because it can help the others if they get the same problem like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Response is in json, so you have to do JSON.parse(data)

Answer (score 0):

i think you won't get errors in success method. try using error function also.

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type:'POST',
   data: {_token:_token, guru_id:guru_id, mapel_id:mapel_id},

   success: function(data){
        $('div.flash-message').html(data);
   },
   error: function(data) {
        printMessageErrors(data.error);
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks for advice. I've update it, but i still have the same problem